# I lost my key store password, I want to update my app on plays store with same keystore

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore, app-update

I lost my key store password, I want to update my app on plays store but don't want to loose my user base.

Can any one suggest me how to update app or how I can get my key store password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing you can do.

Comment: Is there any api or solution available to get keystore password

Comment: Your situation is less hopeless than if you'd lost they keystore itself.  You just need to guess your own password.

Comment: hit and try your password is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the answer is there's absolutely no way to update your app with your keystore without the password.

You have to unlist your app and build with a new keystore, list a new one. Users will not see the updated app because the listing is now pointing at a different entry.

Please keep your keystore file like your life.

Comment: Yes, from the developers site: "Your private key is required for signing all future versions of your app. If you lose or misplace your key, you will not be able to publish updates to your existing app. You cannot regenerate a previously generated key."  https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html